# How to have email & website hosted by different hosts (Weebly/GoDaddy)

Tags: dns, weebly

I've currently got my website & domain hosted by GoDaddy. I've put together a replacement site at Weebly. I'd like to keep GoDaddy as our email host for the time being.

When I update my A records to point to Weebly for the website (see below), the email starts playing up. The MX record has not been changed.

Currently, we can send emails but no emails are being received.

Weebly support have said all I have to do is update my A record, and everything should be fine. GoDaddy support weren't helpful at all, but I understand that, as why would they support the process of me migrating of to another company.

I'm confused though, because the MX records have to be a hostname, rather than IP, but then the MX records use the A records to find the mail server...

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.
Cameron.

Type    Name             Value          TTL
A       @                199.34.228.75  600 seconds

A       admin            199.34.228.75  600 seconds

CNAME   autoconfig       @              1 Hour

CNAME   autoconfig.admin @              1 Hour

CNAME   autodiscover     @              1 Hour

CNAME   autodiscover.admin  @           1 Hour

CNAME   cpanel           @              1 Hour

CNAME   ftp              @              1 Hour

CNAME   mail             @              1 Hour

CNAME   webdisk          @              1 Hour

CNAME   webdisk.admin    @              1 Hour

CNAME   webmail          @              1 Hour

CNAME   whm              @              1 Hour

CNAME   www              @              1 Hour

CNAME   www.admin        @              1 Hour

CNAME   _domainconnect  _domainconnect.gd.domaincontrol.com 1 Hour

MX      @                mail.amsvet.com.au (Priority: 0)   1 Hour

TXT     @                v=spf1 a mx ptr include:secureserver.net ~all  1 Hour

TXT     admin            v=spf1 a mx ptr include:secureserver.net ~all  1 Hour

SRV _autodiscover._tcp.@    0 0 443 cpanelemaildiscovery.cpanel.net 1 Hour

Comment: Not sure why someone down-voted your question. It's logical, happens to lots of people and needed a solution. But, I countered that ;)

Comment: It was probably someone from GoDaddy :D

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, most likely, that you are pointing the A Record for mail.amsvet.com.au to @ (your root domain) BUT your MX Record is pointed to mail.amsvet.com.au

In other words, you are pointing the mail A Record to the Root amsvet.com.au but the Root is now pointed to Weebly's IP. So, when emails are being delivered to your email address they are being sent to the Weebly server because that's where your mail.amsvet.com.au is pointed.

~

It looks like you have changed this back to use GoDaddy's Hosting for your root A Record and it's pointed to 23.229.154.129 (if I have gotten the domain correctly, from what you have posted)

Instead of pointing the mail.amsvet.com.au A Record to @ change the @ to 23.229.154.129 (And of course point your root back to Weebly). That should resolve it.

Recap, change:

```
A @ 23.229.154.129
```

to

```
A @ 199.34.228.75
```

~

Change:

```
A mail @
```

to:

```
A mail 23.229.154.129
```

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, that makes sense. Do I need to delete the CNAME record as well for Mail?

Comment: WOW,.. it must have been late, I was tired, and I missed that. You wouldn't normally have a CNAME for mail, it's usually an A Record pointed to the Root @ or there is just an * (asterix) A Record as a wildcard for any sub-domain. In this case,, if there is a specific CNAME Record for mail, you can delete the mail CNAME and add an A Record for mail pointed to 23.229.154.129  ~Basically they are doing the same thing, but you can point the A Record to an IP address. (it shouldn't allow you to have both, so you'll need to delete the CNAME first)

Comment: **Glad I didn't make any qualms about the type of support you received, as mine wasn't much better haha.. oops. I am fairly confident that this will resolve your issue, nevertheless!

Comment: Haha awesome, that makes sense. Thanks so much for your help, I will give the new settings ago.